# JVM Crash prevented by jconsole.exe

Tags: java, multithreading, maven, javafx, video-capture

I am currently developing a JavaFX application with amazone corretto 8, an embedded SQLite DB and a WebCam Capture API developed by Sarxos using Maven. The application itself runs smoothly and requires around 1.2 GB of RAM at full load.

Unfortunately, when repeatedly loading and terminating threads with an executor service for video streams, my JDK crashes. However, when I try to conduct a root cause analysis with the jconsole, the crash is not reproducible.

Any idea how I can determine the root cause for the crash, or how the crash is prevented by the jconsole?
It would be hard to reproduce the extensive amount of memory, but here is the code for the video stream:

```
 /* Method to initialize WebCam 
 * by:
 * Closing open WebCam
 * Opening WebCam based on Index position
 * Referring to method to start WebCam feed/stream to ImageView
 */
public static void initializeWebCam(final int webCamIndex) {
    
    executorService = createFixedTimeoutExecutorService(2, 3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
    
    Task<Void> iniWebCamTask = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            if (webCam != null) {disposeWebCamCamera();}
            webCam = Webcam.getWebcams().get(webCamIndex);
            webCam.open();
            startWebCamStreamTask();
            //stop Camera if WebCam is no longer in scene
            webCamPane.sceneProperty().addListener((obs, oldScene, newScene) -> {
                if (newScene == null) {
                    disposeWebCamCamera();
                    executorService.shutdownNow(); 
                    mbc.ewatson.App.log.info("Shutting down camera streaming thread");
                } 
            });
            
            return null;
        }
    };



/*
 * method which starts the WebCam stream
 * by:
 * creating a updated/atomic Reference which
 * sets image to null and flushing buffer/ cache
 * updated image from if loop 
 */
protected static void startWebCamStreamTask() {

    stopCamera = false;

    Task<Void> streamImageTask = new Task<Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            final AtomicReference<WritableImage> ref = new AtomicReference<>();
            BufferedImage img = null;
            while (!stopCamera) {
                try {
                    if ((img = webCam.getImage()) != null) {            
                        ref.set(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(img, ref.get()));
                        img.flush();
                        //JavaFX thread
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageProperty.set(ref.get());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

/*Creates an executor service with a fixed pool size, that will time 
 * out after a certain period of inactivity.
 * 
 * @param poolSize The core- and maximum pool size
 * @param keepAliveTime The keep alive time
 * @param timeUnit The time unit
 * @return The executor service
 */
public static ExecutorService createFixedTimeoutExecutorService(int poolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit timeUnit){
    ThreadPoolExecutor e = 
            new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, poolSize,
                keepAliveTime, timeUnit, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
        e.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
        return e; 
     
 }
```

Here is the error log:

Juli 20, 2020 2:15:27 NACHM. ..view.trialpoints.edit.ErprobungspunkteRightFileInput$createFileInputObjects lambda$startWebCamStreamTask$4
INFORMATION: Running Camera
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: -1073740940 (Exit value: -1073740940)
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:504)
at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:394)
at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:100)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)

Comment: Do you have a crash log like `hs_err_pid123.log`?

Comment: And why do you develope a JavaFX app with such an outdated JDK? A lot of bugs have been fixed since these prehistoric times.

Comment: I updated by entire Project to run on amazone corretto JDK 11 and run it using mvn clean javafx:run. However, the crash still occurs when not running jconsole.